# How to change the image names in sql server to keep them in android drawable folder?

Tags: android

In my project I need to **display the images**. We have the image names in database and I need to keep those images in drawable folder. **But before keeping those 
images in drawable folder, the image names contained special symbols, capital letters etc.** So when I tried to copy those images in drawable folder it is not supporting
those special characters and spaces. So I need to change the image names which is not a problem. **But my problem is if I change the image names I should also change those names in database.** 
My images are more than 800 in number. So is there any solution for this or changing everything manually is the only solution? Please help me regrading this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have to think about a good algorithm to preserve the link between an image in res and an image in your db.

For example

DB NAME: My_Image_Number_3_.jpg -> RES NAME: my_image_number_3.jpg
In this simple case the transformation is only a toLoweCase

Answer (score 1):

Drawable resources (or any other XML resource) **do not** support capital letters. You'll either need to store your images on the SD card, on a webserver, or in the [Assets](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) folder.

Honestly, storing 800 images in the Drawable folder seems like a very bad idea. Likewise, if you store the in the Assets folder, it will most likely make your application size quite large. Unless the images are *very* small in size, I would recommend downloading them from a webserver onto the SD card after the user installs and runs the application the first time. This will keep your .apk file small.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "quick and dirty" C# algorithm I used in a recent project to rename >1000 resources for Android.  I iterated over each file in the project folder and called this method for each filename to rename it.  It is a "throw away" piece of code so I didn't bother with using a string builder etc.  Could be better, but it does the job!

```
private String formatName(String name) 
    {
        String result = name.ToLower();

        result = result.Replace("?", "");
        result = result.Replace("'", "");
        result = result.Replace("`", "");
        result = result.Replace(" ", "_");
        result = result.Replace("-", "_");

        if (Char.IsDigit(result.ToCharArray()[0])){
            result = "num" + result;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

You could run the same string replaces in a SQL query to update your DB.